Why is code not executing after do-catch block in Swift?
I am experiencing unexpected behaviour where code directly following a do-catch block is not executed.
As part of a larger project, I need to catch all errors, but ignoring a specific error (representing user cancellation).
I am using catch let error where error as? ExampleError != .exampleIgnoredError to catch errors that are not equal to the ignored error case.
When the example function either does not throw an error, or throws an error that is not equal to .ignoredError, code following the do-catch executes. However when the error is equal to .ignoredError, the catch block is not executed (as expected) but neither is the code following it. (In this case the print("do-catch completed") line and beyond.
I have produced the following example which encapsulates this behaviour. Compiled with Xcode 15.4, minimum deployment iOS 16.4, running on an iPhone on 17.5.1.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var processing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack{
                Button {
                    processing = true
                    Task {
                        do {
                            print("Attempting task")
                            try await exampleTask()
                            print("Task succeeded")
                        } catch let error where error as? ExampleError != .exampleIgnoredError {
                            print("Error caught")
                        }
                        print("do-catch completed")
                        processing = false
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Run")
                }
                .disabled(processing)
                .opacity(processing ? 0 : 1)
                ProgressView()
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .padding()
                    .opacity(processing ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func exampleTask() async throws {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5000000000)
        throw ExampleError.exampleIgnoredError
    }
    
    enum ExampleError: Error {
        case exampleIgnoredError
        case exampleError
    }
}

I am aware that I can easily work around this problem by explicitly catching the ignored error and doing nothing before catching all errors, or checking the error type in the catch block. However I feel like the behaviour I am experiencing is not expected and I would be grateful to understand why it is taking place.

catch let error as ExampleError then add a second catch to catch all other errors

Yes, as I mentioned at the end of my post this is the obvious solution, but my question is WHY am I experiencing this behaviour and not what the easy fix to it is.

@LeoDabus also bear in mind the correct syntax for catching a specific error (specific case of specific enum) would be catch ExampleErrorType.ExampleError. I can't use as to match a specific case, only type.

"Why" questions like this are not very answerable. Why do you think print("do-catch completed") should still be executed even when the code before that line threw an error that is not caught?

I would expect with Swift that the uncaught error would result in a runtime exception, and therefore the lack of an exception suggested to me that the execution would continue. I now understand that as the error is propagated outside of the do-catch and 'consumed'/discarded by Task which is why it wasn't popping up elsewhere. This behaviour is discussed at length here, but to me felt quite un-swift like and therefore unexpected.

@Sweeper and yes, I appreciate "Why" questions are difficult to answer but in this case really any answer would've been satisfactory - I just wanted to understand why it was occurring and less why it had been designed this way. I understand what's going on now and will write my own answer in due course. Alternatively the question can be deleted as my lack of understanding had more to do with the implementation of Task than anything specific to do-catch.

I think this question would be more focused and correct if it was rephrased to focus on SwiftUI. The behaviour you're seeing here has nothing to do with Swift the language. You have an uncaught error being propagated to a library that chooses to respond one way or another to it. The question is about the library, not the language. All the pattern matching, "ignored error" stuff, etc. is a red herring. You'd see the same behaviour from throw SomeError() with no do/catch at all.

The catch block does not catch all possible errors, so any error not caught by the catch block is still thrown, and interrupts the execution, so the rest of the code, like print("do-catch completed"), does not run.
Compare this with the case where you do the same thing, but outside of a Task, and inside a regular, non-throwing function. The compiler would emit an error such as "Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive".
Task { ... } behaves differently, because it has an initialiser that takes a throwing closure. Not all errors in your closure is caught, so the closure is a throwing closure, and the Task { ... } call resolves to this initialiser. This creates a Task<Void, Error> that you immediately discard, so the error is just ignored. Task won't fatalError() or anything like to crash your app.
To catch the error thrown in a Task, you can try await its value in another do...catch block, or just await the result, which is a Result<Void, Error>.
